# adaptive parallel payment with recurring billing

Tags: paypal

Please guide me how should i implement recurring payment with parallel payment.Scenario is like this---There is customer A who buy a recurring billing product and for that first time he pays some amount the payment should be split and go to three accounts and from next month onwards automatically some amount should be deducted from his account and that amount should also split and go to three accounts.Please guide me is there any api that allow to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Recurring Payments and Parallel Payments are completely separate from each other. You can't use the two together. Parallel Payments is part of our Adaptive Payment feature which does not support Recurring Payments at all. Adaptive Payments has their own equivalent to Recurring Payments through the Preapproval API calls but you can't split that payment up unfortunately.

Recurring Payments and Recurring Billing are also different products. Recurring Billing is for Payflow merchants and Recurring Payments is the PayPal version. It's kind of confusing.

I can get you some documentation or answer further questions.